# Solving Algebraic Riccati Equation by using Newton-Raphson's method?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, numerical-methods, optimal-control, newton-raphson

Assume that we have a function called $$F(X) = 0$$

That function can be written as the Algebraic Riccati Equation:

$$F(X) = A^T X + XA - XBR^{-1}B^TX + Q = 0$$

Where the solution to the equation is matrix $X$.

To do a Newton-Raphson solveing method. I need to use this equation:

$$X_{i+1} = X_{i} - F'(X_{i})^{-1}F(X_{i})$$

Where $F'(X)$ is the jacobian function of $F(X)$ and $X_{i+1}$ is going the be the solution to the Algebraic Riccati Equation.

My question is:

How can I find the derivative of $F(X)$ ? Can I just assume that the derivative is:

$$F'(X) = A^T + A - XBR^{-1}B^T$$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$F'(X):H\in M_n\rightarrow A^TH+HA-HUX-XUH$ where $U=BR^{-1}B^T$.

Let $K=F'(X_i)^{-1}F(X_i)$.

At each step, you must solve in $K$ this linear equation:

$A^TK+KA-KUX_i-X_iUK=A^TX_i+X_iA-X_iUX_i+Q$, or

$(A^T-X_iU)K+K(A-UX_i)=A^TX_i+X_iA-X_iUX_i+Q$, which is a Sylvester equation.

EDIT 1. Answers to the first three comments.

I don't need any dot product or "fourth order tensor"!!! $F'(X)$ is a derivative and not a gradient. Stop to read the matrix cookbook; you don't understand that you do.

$F$ is a function from $M_n$ to $M_n$. Then, its derivative, in $X\in M_n$, $F'(X)$ is a LINEAR application from $M_n$ to $M_n$; we assume that it is a bijection in $X_i$ and, therefore $F'(X_i)(K)=F(X_i)$. One cannot do simpler!

Last point. A Sylvester equation in the unknown matrix $K$, is a linear equation in the form $AK+KB=C$.

cf.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation

Matlab has a solver dedicated to this type of equation.

EDIT 2. Answer to Daniel Mårtensson . Your below comment: "but where do I update $K$ then?" shows that you did not understand one word of my post...

I rewrite. One iteration consists in that follows.

i) input. $X_i$

ii) Solve in $K$ (using Matlab): $(A^T-X_iU)K+K(A-UX_i)=A^TX_i+X_iA-X_iUX_i+Q$

The equation depends on $X_i$; then $K$ depends on $X_i$.

iii) output. $X_{i+1}=X_i-K$ (and not $X_i+K$).

Comment: I assume that $F'(X):H$ is referring to the double dot product between the fourth order tensor $F'(X)$ and second order tensor $H$? Since the [derivative of a matrix with respect to a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Other_matrix_derivatives) is a fourth order tensor.

Comment: It is also not immediately clear (at least not to me) where the final Sylvester equation came from. So maybe it would be worth adding that $F'(X_i):K=F(X_i)$. Now buy using the definition of that double dot product the final Sylvester equation can be obtained.

Comment: What is a sylvester equation ? Is it the derivative of the riccati equation?

Comment: So....the Sylvester equation is the derivative equation of the riccati equation?

Comment: So let me make this clear! I need to find $$K = F'(X)^{-1}F(X)$$ to find the new $X_{1+i}$ from $X_{1+i} = X_i + K$. I can find $K$ from $$AK + KB = C$$.......but where do I uptade $K$ then?

Answer (score 2):

Let a lowercase letter stand for the corresponding vectorized matrix, e.g.
$$f={\rm vec}(F), \,\,\, x={\rm vec}(X)$$
Write the function and its differential
$$\eqalign{
 F &= A^TX + XA - XPX + Q \cr
dF &= A^T\,dX + dX\,A - dX\,PX -XP\,dX \cr
}$$
and vectorize
$$\eqalign{
df &= (I\otimes A^T+A^T\otimes I-I\otimes XP-X^TP^T\otimes I)\,dx \cr
J=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
 &= M - (I\otimes XP) - (PX\otimes I)^T \cr
}$$
Note that $$M=(I\otimes A^T+A^T\otimes I)$$ is constant between iterations and only needs to be calculated once.

Then we have the standard Newton iteration
$$\eqalign{
 Js &= f \cr
 x_+ &= x - s \cr
}$$
All of the Kronecker products are sparse, so by utilizing the sparse solvers from your matrix library, you can solve moderately-sized systems with this simple method.

Comment: How would it be if the Riccati Equation was discrete? It would be not possible to find the derivative of it? Maybe I should learn numerical jacobian insted ?

Comment: Can you not show this as a real example so I can mark this as an accepted answer?